# Anyone knows the algorithm used by NullSpace function?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, implementation-details

`NullSpace` function gives a list of vectors that forms a basis for the null space of the input matrix.

When the rank of the input argument matrix $M_{m\times n}$ is exactly $n-1$, then the null space becomes the only non-zero null vector $Z$ of $M$ such that: $M\cdot Z=0$, which can also be obtained by singular value decomposition of $M$.

But by comparing the time consumption of `SingularValueDecomposition` and `NullSpace`, the latter is usually much faster, this indicates they are using different algorithms.

Then: what is the algorithm used by `NullSpace` function? It seems there is no clue [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NullSpace.html).

Comment: Depends on the type of matrix. For example if it is exact and numeric e.g. all integers, `NullSpace` will use some manner of Gaussian elimination and that will be faster than (exact) SVD. Absent some indication of matrix type and size though everything is just speculation.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Are you aware of which "Method" would be most suitable in dealing with a symbolic (5 variables), large (666x667) but sparse (<10%) matrix? And is there any literature available on the performance of these methods in various context?

Comment: @DaveWasHere I doubt any method would handle a matrix of that size unless the sparseness pattern made it exceptionally well behaved. But I'd pick `OneStepRowReduction` for this. (Except...sometimes `DivisionFreeRowReduction` performs better. Heuristics for this choice are not so easy to come by.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you for the answer! So should I understand that in such complicated cases the option Automatic is to avoid? To me this makes more sense since we "help" Mathematica to make a choice causing it to "think less" in principle.

Comment: @DaveWasHere Offhand I don't know which of the two the `Automatic` will select. But if you want to force one or the other method then by all means set that option explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NullSpace works on both numerical and symbolic matrices.

and implied by your link, under "Details" subsection, "Method" would sort of refer to the algorithm NullSpace uses.

> Possible settings for the Method option include "CofactorExpansion", "DivisionFreeRowReduction", and "OneStepRowReduction". The default setting of Automatic switches among these methods depending on the matrix given.

So it depends on the matrix entries. So, as Daniel was saying, there is probably some form of Gaussian elimination at play.